# Anharmonic effects in crystals, help with intuition

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, vibrations, anharmonic-oscillators

I've been reading a bit about how it is necessary to consider anharmonic effects in crystals if one wants to properly understand things like thermal expansion etc. So for example [here](https://books.google.fi/books?id=SHzeQ49ZlH4C&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22asymmetry%20of%20mutual%20repulsion%22&source=bl&ots=QNKhPU2lwk&sig=ACfU3U1xMkSNumsu2Rbih9ykteNeCmeojA&hl=fi&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFzfHCmuv_AhV8QvEDHc2kCFoQ6AF6BAgoEAM#v=onepage&q=%22asymmetry%20of%20mutual%20repulsion%22&f=false):
[image]

So the cubic term is said to represent 'asymmetry of mutual repulsion' and the fourth-order one 'large amplitude weakening' of vibrations. How could one come to understand these intuitively? How does one look at a cubic etc. term and come up with this explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One intuitive way to see how the cubic and quartic term affect the dynamics is by plotting the potential energy and imagining the trajectory of the particle with a fixed energy in the potential:
[image: Potential energy of the harmonic oscillator (black line) and the anharmonic oscillator (red line).]

Here, the black line shows the harmonic oscillator potential and the red line the anharmonic case with $b=-0.05$ and $c=0.01$ and the dashed black line indicates the energy of the system. You can see that the potential of the anharmonic oscillator is now not symmetric around $X=0$ due to the $bX^3$ contribution. This will result in the motion to be "easier" on one side than on the other side. The influence of $cX^4$ is that for the same $X$, the potential energy is larger. The result is that motion is constrained in a smaller displacement region.

One very useful way to understand dynamics is also to look at phase portraits (or flow in phase space), which one can obtain by solving Hamilton's equation of motion

$$\dot{X} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial P} = \frac{P}{m}$$
$$\dot{P} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial X} = - (2aX + 3bX^2 + 4cX^3)$$

$$E = \frac{P^2}{2M} + aX^2 + bX^3 + cX^4$$

with a constant, but fixed energy $E$. The phase portrait tells you the expected trajectory in phase space given the system has a constant energy $E$. For $E=2000$ as in the plot above, the phase portrait is shown below (obtained numerically, using a symplectic Euler integrator). Both the "asymmetry" and "amplitude weakening" are clearly visible in the phase space trajectory for the anharmonic oscillator, whereas the phase space trajectory for the harmonic oscillator is a symmetric ellipse.

[image: Phase portrait of harmonic and anharmonic oscillator.]

Here is the code to create the plots I've put here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Potential(X,a,b,c):
        return a*X**2 + b*X**3 + c*X**4

# Define coefficients for harmonic ("_h") and anharmonic ("_a") cases:
a_h = 10.0
b_h = 0.0
c_h = 0.0

# Initial condition, for integrator
X0_h = -14.14
P0_h = 0.0

a_a = a_h
b_a = -0.05
c_a = 0.01

# Initial condition, for integrator
X0_a = -12.765
P0_a = 0.0 

X = np.arange(-20,20,0.1)
plt.plot(X,Potential(X,a_h,b_h,c_h),color="k",label=rf"$a={a_h}, b = {b_h}, c = {c_h}$")
plt.plot(X,Potential(X,a_a,b_a,c_a),color="red",label=rf"$a={a_a}, b = {b_a}, c = {c_a}$")
plt.xlabel(r"$X$")
plt.ylabel(r"$U(X)=aX^2+bX^3+cX^4$")
plt.plot(X,2000*np.ones(len(X)),linestyle="dashed",color="k")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

def Integrator(X0,P0,a,b,c,dt,tstep):
        # X0,P0 : Initial position and momentum
        # a,b,c : coefficients in anharmonic potential
        # dt : time step
        # tstep : number of time steps

        # Create list for all propagated positions and momenta
        Xl = [X0]
        Pl = [P0]
        Xi = X0
        Pi = P0
        for i in range(tstep):
                # gradient of potential of time t_i = i*dt
                # with position of oscillator X(t_i)
                dU = 2*a*Xi + 3*b*Xi**2 + 4*c*Xi**3

                # Euler step for momenta
                Pn = Pi - dt * dU
                # Euler step for positions
                Xn = Xi + dt * Pn

                # Buffer
                Xi = Xn
                Pi = Pn
                Xl.append(Xi)
                Pl.append(Pi)
        return Xl,Pl


dt_h = 0.0001
tstep_h = 15000
dt_a = dt_h / 10
tstep_a = tstep_h * 10
Xh,Ph = Integrator(X0_h,P0_h,a_h,b_h,c_h,dt_h,tstep_h);
Xa,Pa = Integrator(X0_a,P0_a,a_a,b_a,c_a,dt_a,tstep_a);

plt.plot(Xh,Ph,color="k",label=rf"$a={a_h}, b = {b_h}, c = {c_h}$")
plt.plot(Xa,Pa,color="red",label=rf"$a={a_a}, b = {b_a}, c = {c_a}$")
plt.xlabel(r"$X$")
plt.ylabel(r"$P$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very illuminating! Did you use python for these plots? May I ask to see the code?

Comment: Sure thing, it is updated in the answer.